# Log changes in Backbone.js Collection, my collection is undefined

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Hey! Im new to Backbone.js, so this is most likely an easy question.

I'm want to console.log my friends collection each time it's changing. So i have binded `all` events in the collection to call my logFunction.. but in the logfunction `this.friends` is undefined. Why?

This is my "app":

```
(function ($) {


       Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({
           //Create a model to hold friend atribute
           name: null
       });


       Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({

           model: Friend,
           //This is our Friends collection and holds our Friend models
           initialize: function (models, options) {
               this.bind("add", options.view.addFriendLi);
               this.bind("all", options.view.logFriendsCollection);

               //Listen for new additions to the collection and call a view function if so
           }
       });

       window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
           el: $("body"),

           initialize: function () {
               this.friends = new Friends(null, { view: this });
           },

           events: {
               "click #add-friend": "showPrompt"
           },


           showPrompt: function () {
               var friend_name = prompt("Who is your friend?");
               var friend_model = new Friend({ "name": friend_name });

               this.friends.add(friend_model);
           },

           addFriendLi: function (model) {
               $("#friends-list").append("<li>" + model.get('name') + "</li>");

           },

           logFriendsCollection: function (args) {
               console.log("Friends", this.friends);
           }

       }); var appview = new AppView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when you bind the view's `logFriendsCollection` method to the the Friend collection that the method also receives the collection's context.  So when you reference `this` in the method, `this` refers to the collection rather than the view.

I was messing around with it on your Fiddler link, and the code that I changed to make it work was

```
           logFriendsCollection: function () {
               console.log("Friends", this);
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `AppView.initialize` you should call `_.bindAll(this, 'logFriendsCollection')` to bind `this` to `AppView`.

Comment: Hmm, maybe i missunderstood you... but this is what the changed code looks like, and this.friends is still undefined: http://jsfiddle.net/UNkMp/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Now it looks like it should work and it does when I just try out `appview.logFriendsCollection()` after calling `new AppView`. Where are you calling `logFriendsCollection()`?

Comment: I thought this would call it when any events were triggered on the collection: `this.bind("all", options.view.logFriendsCollection);` in the Friends collection. I want it to be called everytime the collection is changed...

Comment: Seems to work with me when I am explicitly calling `appview.friends.add(new Friend())`.

Comment: ponzao, does the second time you bind `logFriendsCollection` overwrite the first time?  So even tho you give `logFriendsCollection` the proper context by adding the line you suggest, the line `this.bind("all", options.view.logFriendsCollection);` then gives the method the context of the collection rather than the view?

Comment: From the documentation: "Callbacks bound to the special "all" event will be triggered when any event occurs, and are passed the name of the event as the first argument." So no I don't think so :/ Have you debugged what `this` refers to in the context?